# How can force python matplotlib to axis to scale linearly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

So here is my python code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M=[]
for i in np.arange(0.01,8,0.01):
    M.append(test(i))
plt.plot(M)
plt.grid(b=True,which="major",color='#666666', linestyle='-',linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Where test(x) is some complicated function.
When i try to plot it python for some plots on X-axis from 1 to 800, but i want have scaled it plot from 0.01 to 8. So scaled down without changing graph.
Due to complicated form of test(x) function, i would like to use arrays, and this method of ploting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index to plot against (essentially your x-axis values):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M=[]
indices = []
for i in np.arange(0.01,8,0.01):
    M.append(test(i))
    indices.append(i)
plt.plot(indices, M)
plt.grid(b=True,which="major",color='#666666', linestyle='-',linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```